# Is it possible to specify time zone for DB data source in PHPStorm?

Tags: database, timezone, phpstorm

I have `UTC` time zone set in my PostgreSQL and `SELECT NOW()` shows me the right date in `psql` console.

I use PHPStorm for development and its database console for accessing my database, but it uses different time zone (Europe/Moscow, which is the time zone of my Mac), and `SELECT NOW()` shows me the time in this time zone (and by the way, the date is wrong, because the Europe/Moscow time zone recently changed its offset to `+3` from `+4`).

I have not found any information on how to tell PHPStorm to use the time zone configured in `postgresql.conf` instead of system's time zone. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've found a solution, but it will affect every time-specific behavior in IDE, e.g. console logs will show datetime in UTC.

The idea is to pass a timezone to VM options. For that we need to modify a file and restart IDE.

For Mac OS X for the latest version of PHPStorm:

```
cp /Applications/PhpStorm.app/Contents/bin/phpstorm.vmoptions ~/Library/Preferences/PhpStorm2016.1/
```

Then add `-Duser.timezone=UTC` to the file, so that it looks something like that:

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx750m
-XX:MaxPermSize=350m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
-Duser.timezone=UTC
```

Comment: I have done it for PhpStorm2017.2 and it doesn't effect(I made restart). I added to coppied file to /Users/aprosciak/Library/Preferences/PhpStorm2017.2/phpstorm.vmoptions  line -Duser.timezone=UTC. Any idea what could go wrong?

Answer (score 5):

verify your timezone with query

```
SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_names
```

now add phpstorm.vmoptions the config off timezone

-Duser.timezone=posix/America/Sao_Paulo

[image]

Apply changes, disconect, synchronize and verify whith`select now()`

Answer (score 0):

After phpstorm.vmoptions file modification with `-Duser.timezone=UTC` line I've seen correct return only from `NOW()` function but incorrect from the queries to a table like `SELECT timestamp FROM ...`

Only adding a variable `timezoneAsRegion` with `false` value to Advanced tab of connection without any phpstorm.vmoptions changes helped me to return correct timezone from the table.

Documentation link: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/data-sources-and-drivers-dialog.html#advancedTab