# Why is Redshift GETDATE() is returning in local timezone?

Tags: timezone, amazon-redshift

Our Redshift cluster seems to be returning timestamps in the local timezone (Pacific/Auckland) instead of UTC even though the [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GETDATE.html) say:

> GETDATE returns the current date and time in UTC

eg:

```
select GETDATE();

2016-08-30 10:22:18.000000
```

should return:

```
2016-08-29 22:22:18.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Redshift wasn't returning dates in localtime at all; my IDE was translating all dates to localtime.

I'm using PHPStorm's database console. Unfortunately there's no way to disable the timezone translation, the best you can do is [change PHPStorm's timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873271/is-it-possible-to-specify-time-zone-for-db-data-source-in-phpstorm) to UTC but that will affect all date related features of the IDE.